# What is the best y-coordinate to look for Ancient Debris in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am wondering where to find ancient debris because I have gone mining for hours and have never found any, whilst in the nether.

Comment: Hi @TtvUndeadBluddy, welcome to Arqade! To expand a bit on what hfanatic mentioned earlier - on Arqade we're mainly focused on answering the sort of questions that require a bit of digging to answer. Something like this is usually on the Minecraft wiki, so I recommend checking there first in future, and if you still can't find it, go ahead and ask a question (and let us know where you've checked) :) Read more here: [Help Center: How To Ask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

From the Minecraft Wiki on [Ancient Debris](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ancient_Debris#Obtaining):

> Up to two blobs may generate per chunk: one blob of 1–4 ancient debris attempts to generate with a periodic normal distribution (similarly to lapis lazuli ore) from levels 8 to 22, and an additional blob of 0–2 ancient debris attempts to generate randomly from levels 8 to 119. On average, Y-level 15 has the most ancient debris.

What this means is, you'll most likely find Ancient Debris around Y-level 15, but it can be anywhere between 8 to 119 (with better chances being between 8-22).